# componentsSeparatedByString omitting substrings surrounded by delimiters?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am trying to divide an input separated by "-" with the help of componentsSeparatedByString

```
NSString *idInput = @"1-S2-1-8214685" //Actually input of a memory-rading operation

NSMutableArray *idBuf = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[idInput componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"]];
```

However, this seems to omit the first substring aswell as the third substring, as idBuf afterwards contains the following:

```
idBuf = {@"",@"S2",@"",@"8214685"}
```

How can I get hold of the two missing substrings?

Whole function:

```
+ (id) buildPlayerwithIdBuffer: (char*)idBuffer andPlayerName: (char*)playerName
{

NSString *idInput = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:idBuffer];
NSString *playerN = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:playerName];
NSString *uniqueServerId;

SFPlayer *resPlayer = [[self alloc]initWithPlayerName:playerN];

    NSMutableArray *idBuf = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[idInput componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"]];
    //[idBuf removeObjectAtIndex:1];

    switch ([[idBuf objectAtIndex:0]characterAtIndex:0]) {
        case '1':
            [idBuf replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:@"us"];
            break;
        case '2':
            [idBuf replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:@"eu"];
            break;
        case '3':
            [idBuf replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:@"kr"];
            break;
        case '6':
            [idBuf replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:@"sg"];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    uniqueServerId = [[idBuf objectAtIndex:2] stringByAppendingString:[idBuf lastObject]];

    [resPlayer setServer:[idBuf objectAtIndex:0]];
    [resPlayer setIdentifier:uniqueServerId];



return resPlayer;


}
```

EDIT: I just checked again, idBuf[0] and idBuf[3] contain the same value, which, displayed as a C String is:

```
"@\xfffffffa\xfffffffb}\xffffffff\x7f"
```

Comment: [For me, it doesn't.](http://ideone.com/KHT7dO)

Comment: I'm with @H2CO3 on this. You might want to post the rest of the surrounding code. The two lines in your example work as expected, so perhaps memory is getting deallocated or otherwise modified.